# How do I test if a subdirectory file is present using RewriteCond?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Given input `http://example.com/foo.html` how would I check if `http://example.com/subdir/foo.html` exists, using `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess`? It feels like

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond subdir%{REQUEST_URI} -f
```

should work, but `REQUEST_URI` behaves unexpectedly (to me) when used within `RewriteCond` compared to when it is used within `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RewriteCond` like this:

```
# file not present in current directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# file present in subdir/ directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir/$0 -f
# rewrite to subdir/ directory
RewriteRule .+ subdir/$0 [L]
```